# MS ACCESS: Exclude a subtotal of a primary group from a grand subtotal

Tags: ms-access, report

I've got a budget report that is broken down by category.  Included in these categories is an OPTIONAL section.  I would like to show the OPTIONALS in the main report but exclude them from the grand total.  Everything works perfectly except I cannot figure out how to exclude (or subtract) the OPTIONALS.  Please see attached image of design view of report.  Thanks![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvYz4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
=Sum(IIf(Category_Optional=True,0,Value))
```

Where Category_Optional=True is any kind of record expression that defined whether you want to exclude a record from the subtotal or not and value is the field you are getting a subtotal on.

Comment: `=Sum(IIF([Category Name] Like "Optional", 0, [Subtotal]))` If I understand, "optional" is a CategoryName value.

Comment: Pretty much yes. Not sure what you actual fields look like but you need an expression that uses record values and defines whether to exclude it from the sum or not. If it is a Category Name string it would be something like `[Category Name]='Optional'` Don't use `LIKE` unless there are wildcards involved. It wastes of processing power.

Comment: Also opt to use single quotes so that any expressions are can be directly copy/pasted in SQL code. It doesn't matter in this case but it is a good habit.

Comment: Not sure which version you are using but I can definitely use single quotes with LIKE on my Access 2010 forms control sources (and I know it does not break all the way to Access 2016). Do you get an error with single quotes?

Comment: Used this and it worked!!  Thanks! =Sum(IIf([CategoryID]='OPTN',0,[Subtotal]))